# sql как обновить таблицу а именно убрать пробел между словами в этом поле

Tags: sql, база-данных

Допустим есть такой столбец = '76 ОСКИ'
и необходимо обновить таблицу чтобы исчез пробел между 76 и ОСКИ явно не указывая номер 76 !
Номера в таблице меняются и необходимо автоматизировать удаление пробельного символа.

```
update temp_table_xxx
set "Склад_1С" = '96ОСКИ'
where "Склад_1С" like '96 ОСКИ';
```

Comment: `UPDATE temp_table_xxx SET "Склад_1С"=REPLACE("Склад_1С", ' ', '');`

Comment: если в начале не известно, то замените конец `replace(field, ' ОСКИ', 'ОСКИ')`

Comment: Всем спасибо, ) Все работает :))